# Insert data into server.....?

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

I am trying to read some specified columns of an excel sheet and with date,mobilenumber and some columns,i am able to read the columns but there is a problem in inserting the values to the data base........................

```
    public static DataTable columnNamessheet2(String excelFile)
    {
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;'";
        string connectionstring = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DebitCare;Data Source=SSDEV7-HP\\SQLEXPRESS";

        using (OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlConnection SqlConn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlConn1.Open();
            OleDbCommand odc1 = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("Select  LOAN_NO,DOB,DEALER_NAME,CUST_MOBILE_NO  FROM [ICICI TW DUMP$]"), conn1);
            conn1.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader1 = odc1.ExecuteReader();
            int LOAN_NO = reader1.GetOrdinal("LOAN_NO");
            int DEALER_NAME = reader1.GetOrdinal("DEALER_NAME");
            int DOB = reader1.GetOrdinal("DOB");
            int CUST_MOBILE_NO = reader1.GetOrdinal("CUST_MOBILE_NO");
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                string LnNumber = reader1.GetValue(LOAN_NO).ToString();
                string cname = reader1.GetValue(DEALER_NAME).ToString();
                string CDOB = reader1.GetValue(DOB).ToString();
                string CMobNo = reader1.GetValue(CUST_MOBILE_NO).ToString();
            }
            DataTable sheetSchema1 = reader1.GetSchemaTable();
            SqlBulkCopy sqlbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlConn1);
            sqlbulk.DestinationTableName = "DebitCare";
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("LnNumber", "CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO");
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("cname", "CUSTOMER_NAME");
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CDOB", "DOB");
            sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CMobNo", "CUST_MOBILE_NO");
            sqlbulk.WriteToServer(reader1);
            return sheetSchema1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: i am geting the error saying.........."The given ColumnName 'LnNumber' does not match up with any column in data source."

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What error message are you getting?

Comment: i am geting the error saying.........."The given ColumnName 'LnNumber' does not match up with any column in data source."

Comment: "CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO" is a column name in database,where as "LOAN_NO" is a column name in excel file ihad problem problem in reading those column with out converting thats the reason i took int ,string and converted\

Answer (score 0):

Then your line

```
sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("LnNumber", "CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO");
```

should say

```
sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add( "LOAN_NO","CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO");
```

here are the docs for this utility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping.aspx

Comment: "CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO" is a column name in database,where as "LOAN_NO" is a column name in excel file ihad problem problem in reading those column with out converting thats the reason i took int ,string and converted\ – Raghu Bandaru

Comment: then shouldn't it be this: sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO", "LOAN_NO");

Comment: The given ColumnName 'CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO' does not match up with any column in data source.

Comment: i should use converted value rite.....the converted values are in the string.................

Comment: I am sorry I got them backwards - its source, destination.

Comment: what you did with the strings is a mystery to me. they are not used anywhere in the code :)

Comment: in my excel file i have to adjust the columns and read them thats the reason i had to use them those column contain the cloumns with,date,mobile like that did u get it nw

Comment: I edited the answer try it. and check out the docs - they have examples.

Comment: i posted a link to docs in the answer. this is the change try : sqlbulk.ColumnMappings.Add( "LOAN_NO","CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO");

Comment: i tried this there are no errors ........when i check the data base there is no data there

Comment: how do you know that your select statement is working corerctly? meaning how do you know that you have data to write?